# Animated UITableView reload causes every cell to load at once

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a table view with 100 cells. At first, it is empty. Then, I call:

```
[_tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
```

As there was nothing in the table view, I need to create several cells. However, I was expecting the table view to ask for 10 (to fit the screen size) cells... not 100 !

It doesn't happen when I simply reload the table view without any animation:

```
[_tableView reloadData];
```

This issue makes the table reloading very slow: is there a way to make it ask for 10 cells only ?

---

#### Edit

Maybe I wasn't clear enough: **At first**, the table has **no entry**. **Then**, I add **100 entries** in my data source, and ask the table to reload: there is no visible cell before the reload, so the `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` solution won't work.

Comment: "I was expecting the table view to ask for 10 cells... not 100 !" Please explain more on what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: The screen should only contain 10 cells, this is why `UITableView` has cell reuse. So when I reload the table view, I expect it to ask for 10 cells, and not the amount indicated in `- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`.

Comment: Ah I see. Got it. So you want to reload only the visible cells am i right ?

Comment: That's right ! But I also want the table to know that there are now 100 cells instead of 0.

Comment: Interesting find! I'd say be sure to file a bug report with Apple.

Comment: Post your code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. A `UITableView` should only load the cells that are visible on the screen, all with reusable cells in order to be fast.

Comment: @MSgambel: I do use reusable cells, it's not the issue. When I call `[_tableView reloadData]`, `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called 100 times instead of 10.

Comment: Still, posting your code for how you configure the tableview could help track down the issue. Maybe you have not configured the `height` of the cells properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this issue occurs only on iOS 5.1 and below. No need to file a bug as it is corrected in iOS 6. Thank you for your answers anyway !

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're inserting new rows in the table, rather than reloading, so why not use:

```
[_tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:... withRowAnimation:...];
```

You may need to insert the section first:

```
[_tableView insertSections:... withRowAnimation:..];
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Let's say I insert 10 rows with this solution, the table view won't know that there are 90 more rows and it won't allow me to scroll.

Comment: You need to add all 100 rows obviously, but that shouldn't cause your data source to be queried unless you're inserting visible rows.

Comment: Well, it doesn't work on iOS 5.1. It seems to be fixed in iOS 6.0. Anyway, this is a bug, and I don't think there is a solution for iOS 5.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to reload lets say 10 cells, the following code will work.

```
        int cellsToReload = 10;

        NSMutableArray *indexPaths = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:cellsToReload];
        for(int x = 0; x < cellsToReload; x++) {

            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:x inSection:0];
            [indexPaths addObject:indexPath];
        }

        [self.theTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
```

In the above code when you reloaded all of the tableview, you were reloading the entire section and not just a few rows. I'm guessing your tableview only had one section.

Comment: As I said, at first the table view has no row. So if I do that, it triggers an error: `attempt to delete row 9 from section 0 which only contains 0 rows before the update`.

Answer (score 0):

`NSArray *paths = [_tableView indexPathsForVisibleRows];`
`[_tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:paths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];`
will do exactly what you need - reload only visible raws, neither more, nor less.

Comment: why couldn't you call reloadData to make your tableview reflect your changed datasource?

Comment: Because I want the reload to be animated.

Comment: I think, you may use series of insertRowsAtIndexPaths calls. Read "Batch Insertion, Deletion, and Reloading of Rows and Sections" chapter in documentation of Table View Programming Guide.